# Filter to show right and cross symbol conditionally with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, filter

i am new in angular.suppose i am showing employee info through **ng-repeat** in tabular format. suppose employee info has one property called **isDeveloper**. if **isDeveloper value is 1** then i will show right symbol in row and **if isDeveloper is 0** then i will show cross symbol in row. how to do it.

the trick is not coming to my head.do i need to achieve it by custom filter or custom directive ? please share the idea with bit of code sample if possible. thanks

Comment: You're obligated to show your attempt, or at the very least your markup.

Comment: it is true...hence i am new in ng and that is the reason trick is not coming to my head to start the code and apologized that could not post any code.

Comment: There are many examples showing how to toggle elements or attributes based on a view model variable. Pick one and give it a go. As it is, your question is off-topic for SO as too broad.

Comment: can u plzz give me a relevant link....thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like that:

```
// Setup the filter
        .filter('customFilter', function () {
            return function (number) {
                if (isNaN(number) || number > 1) {
                    return number;
                } else {
                    if (number === 1) {
                        return "cross"
                    } else if (number === 0) {
                        return "arrow"
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

the html usage:

```
<td>{{idDeveloper | customFilter}} other text</td>
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jp6oq2tp/

Comment: give me html so i can understand how to apply the filter at td level of table.

Comment: if possible add jsfiddle link for better clarity. thanks

Comment: <td>{{idDeveloper | customFilter}}</td>

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-if`. In the column in which you enter it, use

```
<td ng-if="person.isDeveloper">&#x2713;</td>
<td ng-if="!person.isDeveloper">&#x2717;</td>
```

At any point of time only one of these will be there.

Comment: i have to show either right symbol or cross symbol. now tell me how to do it by ng-if?

Comment: if i use two ng-if then two td will be shown i guess but i want to show one td in which i have to show right or cross symbol.

Comment: @MonojitSarkar No. Only one of them will be there. elements containing ng-if only appear in the dom if they evaluate to true.

Comment: you are wrong. see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/jp6oq2tp/2/  if use ng-if with span and saw both are showing instead of one.

Comment: @MonojitSarkar You were using version 1.0.0 of angular. Ng-if was introduced in later versions. I highly recommend you to use a new version of angular. And as far as my answer is concerned, it works perfectly with your fiddle with new angular version. I have updated your [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jp6oq2tp/4/). Have a look.

Comment: yes u r right. when i set angular v1.2.1 then it works but when i set angular v1.4.8 then no output comes....v1.4.8 has any bug? see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/jp6oq2tp/8/    no output comes :(

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use ng-class:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

```
<td><span ng-class="{cross: isDeveloper==0, right: isDeveloper==1}">content<span></td>
```

Comment: can we do it by custom filter?

Comment: yes, but you need to create a custom filter. which is much effort as ng-class

Comment: can please discuss with sample code to achieve it by custom filter.

Comment: can we show Unicode character by ng-class....i am not sure because i need some function which will return Unicode character for right or cross symbol.

Comment: basically i do not want to display 0 or 1 as value rather i want to show right or cross mark or symbol in that place....how can i do it by ng-class?